# Escaping xml characters in Codeigniter/php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, codeigniter

I am trying to save data from my xml file into the mysql database using codeigniter & php. But I couldn't find a way to escape special xml characters to save my data from the xml file to my table, cache_table.

```
 Code:

 $xml_source = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"),file_get_contents('XML/customer.xml'));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_source);  
foreach($xml as $row )
{
 $attr = $row->attributes();

$results[] = array('CustomerAccountNumber' => $this->db->escape_str($attr->CustomerAccountNumber),'Desciption' => $this->db->escape_str($attr->Desciption) ):

$this->db->insert_batch('cache_cust',$results);
```

But I am getting this error:

**Error:**

> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 37: parser error : Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values.

**customer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Rows>
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="12" Name="Arj" Desciption="PJ psm" />  
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="1" Name="Aj" Desciption="*/Artic" />
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="2" Name="smla" Desciption="& light" />
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="3" Name="alik" Desciption="*/Artic" />
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="4" Name="wqla" Desciption="" />
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="5" Name="walij" Desciption="16-17" />
<Row CustomerAccountNumber="6" Name="li" Desciption="sales@llil.com" />
</Rows>
```

How can I avoid this error and avoid special xml characters so that my code save all the records from the xml file into the database?

Comment: can you paste your xml data ?

Comment: @GBD I have added the xml data in the question.thanks.

Comment: Characters that have a special meaning in XML are unlikely to have a special meaning in SQL. Why do you think you need to escape anything?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario i meant i want to escaoe xml entities so that i could save records into my database.i m new bie and i have got no idea how i can achieve this in php/codeigniter.

Comment: Then I have good news: you don't have to. XML entities are harmless for databases.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario lolz then why i am getting errors?In short,how can I avoid these kind of errors so that i could save data into my database??

Comment: Your error happens several lines before your database stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to review the htmlentities to encode and html_entity_decode to restore them back.  Using the htmlentities will allow you to not have to worry about replacing each of the special characters like the ampersand individually and it will replace the arrows as well.  I believe the escape_str will take care of the quotes for you.

The documentation found in the links below should assist you with any unanswered questions.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all:

```
Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values.
```

So your XML is invalid. How did it get corrupted in the first place? Probably because of this:

```
$xml_source = str_replace(array("&amp;", "&"), array("&", "&amp;"),file_get_contents('XML/customer.xml'));
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord will take care of escaping strings with quote characters in them i.e. `'`, `"`. So you won't have to use something like [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) explicitly. Other XML characters will be fine and won't have to be escaped e.g. `<`, `>`.

Also you (or someone else) spelled "Desciption" wrong in the XML attributes.